# Making a POST request in Angular from a Service

Tags: angular, post

I'm struggling to create a POST request in Angular v7 from a Service. My service class already has some get requests in it that pull data from my api. Now I need to post data and I can't figure out the format/syntax (still new to angular).

In VSCode I can see it says `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type
'void'.`

Here is the service

`Shipment.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Ziptastic } from '../interfaces/ziptastic';
import { ReturnShipment } from '../interfaces/return-shipment';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShipmentService {
  private shipmentCreation = 'api/ReturnShipmentQueues';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  }

  submitShipment(rShip: ReturnShipment) {
    this.http.post(this.shipmentCreation, rShip, httpOptions)
    .subscribe(
      data => {console.log('AllthePost' + JSON.stringify(data));},
      err => {console.log("error occurred");}
    );

  }
  private handleError(handleError: any): import("rxjs").OperatorFunction<any[], any> {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not subscribe within your service, instead subscribe in the component, also **`return`** the http.post from your service

```
 return this.http.post(this.shipmentCreation, rShip, httpOptions)
```

and your component code should be,

```
this.shipmentServic.submitShipment(shipObj).subscribe(response => {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Construct a POST request which interprets the body as JSON and returns it.
 *
 * @return an `Observable` of the body as an `Object`.
 */
post(url: string, body: any | null, options?: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders;
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams;
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'json';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<Object>;
```

It's weird because http.post returns observable and iis  possible to subscribe to it

Comment: what is you version of rxjs?

Comment: Is this a new question or an answer?